# AVPlayerViewController fadeout on completion

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, cabasicanimation, avplayerviewcontroller

I using AVPlayerViewController which I want to fadeout when the video ends... I can capture the end-of-video event, and I the code put together for AVPlayer works, but for the AVPlayerViewController not.

```
self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: videoURL)
self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
self.streamPlayer =  AVPlayerViewController()
self.streamPlayer.player = self.player
self.streamPlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 128, y: 222, width: 512, height: 256)
```

This code works too, but goes full screen- I don't want full screen...

```
//self.presentViewController(self.streamPlayer, animated: true) {
//   self.streamPlayer.player!.play()
//}
```

I use this?

```
self.view.addSubview(self.streamPlayer.view)
self.streamPlayer.player!.play()
```

The event capture ..

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "finishedPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
}
```

The event Code ...

func finishedPlaying(myNotification:NSNotification) {

```
    let fadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    fadeOut.fromValue = 1.0
    fadeOut.toValue = 0.0
    fadeOut.duration = 8.0
    fadeOut.delegate = self
    fadeOut.setValue("video", forKey:"fadeOut")
    fadeOut.removedOnCompletion = false
    fadeOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
```

This line does nothing with AVPlayerViewController/With AVPlayer it fades out nicely ?

```
    playerLayer.addAnimation(fadeOut, forKey: nil)
```

This simply removes AVPlayerViewController, plan B if I cannot make this work!

```
    //self.streamPlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
    print("VIDEO finished")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AVPlayerViewController has it's own AVPlayerLayer and does not know about the AVPlayerLayer you created. Thus, the line
    playerLayer.addAnimation(fadeOut, forKey: nil)
has no effect. You should set or animate the alpha value of AVPlayerViewController's view. For the fade animation you may want to look at the +[UIView animateWithDuration:(...)] methods and call
    self.streamPlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
in the completion handler.